Show sheet when detail item is not nil (Binding extension)
I would like to show a detail sheet when the detail item is not nil, without an additional boolean @State variable:
.sheet(isPresented: $optionalDetailItem.notNilBinding()) {
    Text("Details")
}

Here's my current code. How to make it work for non-Sendable items? If I remove the Sendable requirement I get the error Capture of 'self' with non-sendable type 'Binding<Optional<T>>' in a '@Sendable' closure.
@available(iOS 13.0, macOS 10.15, *)
public extension Binding {
    /// Careful, never set this to `true`.
    func notNilBinding<T: Sendable>() -> Binding<Bool> where Value == Optional<T> {
        Binding<Bool>(
            get: { self.wrappedValue != nil },
            set: { newValue in
                if !newValue {
                    wrappedValue = nil
                } else {
                    // In this context we cannot not know what to set `wrappedValue` to.
                    fatalError("This must not be set to `true`.")
                }
            }
        )
    }
}


did you try this https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/sheet(item:ondismiss:content:)

Works perfectly, thanks. I saw it before in autocomplete, tried it, got a compilation error and didn't investigate further. Now it works. What if it's not for a sheet but another use case where there's no special initializer though?

please update the question, then someone can answer

You answered the current one perfectly. If you post your answer I will accept it and leave the question as is.

@Immanuel if you do pos an answer, please summarize the solution in your answer rather than just posting a link,

You can use this method sheet(item:onDismiss:content:) to show a sheet if data is not nil.
@State private var optionalDetailItem: DetailItem?

When the value of optionalDetailItem is set to non nil, the sheet will be displayed
.sheet(isPresented: $optionalDetailItem) {
    Text("Details")
}

